# How to change the container of scheme in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to IOS development and am figuring to to this. How do change the container of scheme in xcode?

I want to change the scheme from project to workspace.

Could not find any option under :
Product > Scheme > Manage Schemes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select Product > Scheme > Manage Schemes. In the sheet that pops up, the cells in the "Container" column are actually dropdown menus. Click on the "Container" cell for the scheme in question, and select the new container.

[image: Manage Schemes sheet]

Comment: Actually I had to open workspace instead of project and then i could see the container option